# AirPods 2nd Generation never connect with Apple TV 4K, yet AirPods 3rd Generation always do

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, airpods

My [Apple TV 4K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#4K_(first_generation)), with the latest tvOS 16.3, never offers to connect with my [AirPods 2nd Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPods#2nd_generation).

- I tried opening the case several inches away.
- I tried opening the case several feet away.
- I tried popping the AirPods into my ear while the Apple TV is playing some content.

Yet with my [AirPods 3rd Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPods#3rd_generation), the moment I grab them the Apple TV offers to connect with a message in the upper right corner.

Both sets of AirPods (2nd Gen & 3rd Gen) are connected to the same personal Apple account. Both work seamlessly with my iPhone.

Is there some way to get Apple TV 4K to notice the AirPods 2nd Generation?

According to [Apple's brochure page](https://www.apple.com/airpods-2nd-generation/), the AirPods 2nd Generation do work with Apple TV. To quote:

> And the AirPods experience is just as amazing whether you’re using them with your iPhone, Apple Watch, iPad, Mac, or Apple TV.

Comment: @JBallin I added a quote from the Apple web site claiming they should work. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Here's another: "AirPods connect immediately, and sound seamlessly switches between your iPhone, Apple Watch, Mac, iPad, and Apple TV. Easy setup, magical results."

Comment: Do they appear in the list of available bluetooth devices? I also assume you are connected with the same Apple ID on both your Apple TV and AirPods?